# php shortcode into jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, prepend

I have a Wordpress based website, and some of the content is loaded through javascript. 
For example:

```
jQuery(".portfolio-fs-slides").css({"display":"none"}).prepend('<div class="portfolio-fs-          slide current-slide portfolio-ppreview"><div class="project-coverslide"></div><div id="content" class="content-projectc contenttextwhite"></div></div>');
```

What I want to do is append this shortcode:  `<?php echo do_shortcode('[daisy]'); ?>`

But as far as I know is not really possible to append php code in javascript. 
Is there any workaround to accomplish this ? 
Thanks!

Comment: The PHP needs to be executed serverside. However you can echo js code to be interpreted by the client.

Comment: so, you're saying to append the echoed shortcode in that function ?

Comment: It should work, yes. What's the result of that PHP snippet?

Comment: `a class="clickable">CLICK HERE</a>`

Comment: I've tried to add `a class="clickable">CLICK HERE</a>` inside that function and it's not working, my website crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi mentioned, the PHP will run serverside, and the JS will run client side.  You can output JS (or parts of your JS) via PHP and have it run client side, e.g.

```
<script>
    // extra code here
    jQuery(".portfolio-fs-slides").css({"display":"none"}).prepend('<div class="portfolio-fs-          slide current-slide portfolio-ppreview"><div class="project-coverslide"></div><div id="content" class="content-projectc contenttextwhite"></div></div>'); 
    <?php echo 'we can output valid js here' ?>
    // more code here
</script>
```

One way to think of this is that since PHP runs server side, it will always run before the JS is parsed.

Put another way, you could have a javascript line like this:

```
console.log(<?php echo $someVariable ?>);
```

Comment: I'm thinking to add it like this: `('.portfolio-fs-viewport').append('<a class="clickable">CLICK HERE</a>');` but I receive this in console : `yntaxError: Unexpected token <`